# write 10 bit values to a char array

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am trying to write 10 bit values (image with a high dynamic range) to a `char *` array. So, if I have an image which is size `10 x 10`, I am assigning an array as:

```
char * buffer = [10 * 10 * 2];
```

The idea is that each pixel can be stored in 2 bytes. Now, on my device I have an API call that can read one line of the image. i.e. I can do something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    char * current = &buffer[i * 10 * 2];
    read_line(current);
    // Map to 10-bit here...
}
```

Now, this function reads in the byte stream. How can I ensure that each 2 byte word is mapped correctly to the 10 bit value, so that when I case this array to a `short` type, each value is the 10 bit pixel value before 0-1023.

Comment: What is the original range? 0~65535 ?

Comment: what type is the data you want to put in the array? For example `uint16_t` is guaranteed to be 2 bytes, this is maybe easier than to use `char`

Comment: Use an `unsigned char*` to save yourself from a load of UB.

Comment: Is read_line from an external library? If so, and it is really using char despite needing 10 bits, read the documentation on how it handles the conversion. If it is your own function, you should change the underlying type to at least uint16, but keep in mind that plain int will usually be the most efficient in terms of speed.

Comment: You need to tell us the data format that `read_line` returns. Does it return packed bits? So, for example, in your case, does it return 10*10 bits = 100 bits, which fits in 13 bytes? Or does it return 2 bytes/pixel?

Comment: It turned out it was returning the top 8 bits in the first character byte and the lower 8 bits in the second byte. So, I could do something like `256 * current[2*i] + current[2*i+1]`

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The format of a line is decided by the `read_line` function. You need to read the documentation of this function to find out what format it uses, and then convert the values you get into your internal format using some bit twiddling.

Or otherwise decide that the format the function uses is better than your internal one, and convert your program to use it directly.